# Title not saved as part of question-draft

Tags: bug, title, draft

When drafting a question, the body and tags are saved, but the title never is- this seems like a clear bug. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you tell us more? Where did this happen? Is it reproducible? What software are you using?

Comment: iOS Safari. It is reproducible, I’ve consistently noticed it for years.

Comment: I don't think this deserves closure; I've been able to reproduce this for years as well (Firefox, multiple versions, multiple operating systems). I derived a possible technical explanation the first time I encountered it, so it never occurred to me that it might be worth fixing, so I'm glad for this bug report.

Comment: No repro with Chrome, it save the title just fine. @wizzwizz4 what OS? Maybe it's another one specific to WebKit browsers.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry From memory: Firefox on Windows 8.1, Windows 10, Debian 10, and Debian 11. Have you confirmed that _Stack Exchange_ is the one saving the title, and not _Chrome_?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 yes it's SE saving the draft, Chrome does not save what I put into form elements, at least not by default. Tested by typing a title, waiting few minutes to make sure draft is being saved, closing the tab, reopening, and [the title is still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivGRH.png).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 perhaps the AJAX responsible for saving is being blocked, any blockers being used? /cc Seeking

Comment: Okay, so there's no reason I should be getting the behaviour I keep getting (it's putting all the fields into `/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask`, so it _should_ be all-or-nothing) – and I'm _not getting it at the moment_. But this happens often enough that I have an entire procedure for dealing with it: does it have something to do with restoring sleeping tabs overwriting the draft, perhaps?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 perhaps, yeah.